# Criar modulo de frete personalizado com tabela de configurações

Tags: php, magento

Estou a criar um modulo para adicionar na loja um novo método de entrega. Segui esse [tutorial](http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/10/14/magento-create-custom-shipping-method/) (não vou transcreve-lo, é grande e não é necessário para a pergunta ).

O novo método leva em conta o país do comprador, o peso do produto ou o peso volumétrico.

O problema aqui é que para definir o valor do frete conforme o peso volumétrico, é preciso criar na área de gestão do módulo uma tabela em que posso adicionar um país e o preencher o seu respectivo divisor (um valor inteiro).

Eu sei definir campos através do ficheiro "system.xml", mas não sei como criar essa tabela dinâmica para receber N linhas, conforme o cliente vai adicionando novos países.